# Как вывести значения произвольных полей WordPress на главной?

Tags: php, wordpress

На страницах есть доп. поле price, надо вывести его на главную, где выводятся плиткой все страницы, но не получается. Картинка страницы и его название выводится, а произвольное поле не могу вывести. В программирование только учусь, опыта практически нет.

```
<div class="grid-wrap">
      <ul class="grid swipe-right" id="grid">

        <?php $args = array('numberposts' => -1,'exclude'    => '438,446,450,2094,2088','orderby'   => 'menu_order','post_type'   => array('page'), 'suppress_filters' => true);
      $pages = get_posts($args);
      //var_dump(get_posts($args));

      ?>

        <?php

        foreach ($pages as $page){
            //var_dump(get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID));
            if (get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID) != ''){
            ?>
            <li> <a href="/<?php echo $page->post_name; ?>" rel="bookmark">
            <? echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID);?>
            <h2 class="entry-title" id="post-<?php echo $page->ID; ?>">
              <?php echo $page->post_title; ?> 

//Вывод произвольного поля с ценой
<?php
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price', true );
?>

            </h2></a>
            </li>
            <?}

        }?>

      <? wp_reset_postdata();
      //query_posts( 'posts_per_page=-1' ); ?>

     </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Произвольное поле - advanced custom field?

Comment: Если это плагин, то нет. Включил отображение произвольных полей через "Настройки экрана - Блоки - (галочка) Произвольные блоки" и под редактором с контентом появилась возможность добавлять произвольные поля. Доп. плагинов для этого не использую.